# ffmpeg - how do I remove a sweep line seen

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp

I am streaming a video over network(rtp) which uses x264 and ffmpeg's h264 on the other side.
Everything is OK as far as there is no packet loss.
When there are packet loss it fixed when key-frame arives.
Instead of immediate refresh it takes about 1-1.5 seconds and it seems like a sweep line which 'cleans' the errors.

Is there a way to make key frames fix errors immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Setting b_intra_refresh = 0 of x264_param_t solves the problem.

Comment: Just note, that removing intra-refresh will increase the latency between the stream and I would suggest not doing that if this is a live stream. [Here is a good article](http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/249) from one of the x264 devs